# adding data or modifying data in powershell

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a CSV file with users and dates in it.
I want to run a powershell script that will modify or add to that list.
I have the modify part down, but I can't get the script right to add a line.
Here is what I have.
The file is users.csv with the following data:

> ```
> Username    Date
> Johnson    3/10/16
> Smith      12/31/15
> Brown      3/9/16
> ```

When the script runs, I want to check the username.  if there is a match, update the date.  if there isn't a match add a new line.
Here is my code:

## Get time parts

```
$date=Get-Date -format d
```

## Get username

```
$user=$env:username
```

## import data and modify

```
($CSV= import-csv c:\users.csv -delimiter ',') | foreach {
   if ($_.username -match $user) {
 $_.date=$date
    }
}
```

## output

```
Export-csv c:\users.csv -notypeinformation -force
```

This will change the date for a user and export the file just fine.
I can't get the code write to read all the usernames and if there isn't a match to add a line at the end with a username and date.

I'm fairly new to powershell.
Thanks for your help
Charles

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$date = Get-Date -format d
$user = $env:username
$csv = ipcsv c:\users.csv
$csv | % {if ($_.username -match $user) {$_.date = $date}}
if ($user -notin $csv.username) {$csv += [pscustomobject]@{Username = $user; Date = $date}}
$csv
```